# publishing your own Symbol site for WinDbg

Tags: windbg, symbols

This is an interesting challenge and I am not sure if anyone out there has undertaken it. I work for a software vendor, selling a large enteprise scale Microsoft.NET based software. Most of the production issues are triaged using DebugDiag or ADPlus dmp files. Our customers often ask us if we could publish our symbols public like Microsoft's http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols site. Any guidance here is much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 8):

You need to set you Symbols Store using [Symstore.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266480.aspx). Then you can [expose it over HTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc901414.aspx) by configuring IIS. You can optionally use [SymProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc901417.aspx) to expose multiple stores as one HTTP symbols server. You can also use [SymSrv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266475.aspx) to connect to different public symbols server, setup local cache and other advanced stuff.

And of course, you can even [build your own symbols server DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266464.aspx) through the [Symbols Server API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc267327.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is an app for that: [SymStore.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681417(VS.85).aspx). It is part of Windbg suite. You should also include the symbols drop step to your build process so it publishes symbols for every release.